# How to get a single paragraph text from a richtextbox when double clicking on it

Tags: richtextbox, paragraph

I'm having some trouble getting control of the WPF richtextbox control.

What I want to is as follows :
I have a RichTextBox control called richTextBox1 that I filled up with data from a database.

I need to get the text on a single line (meaning - a single paragraph) when I click the control.

All I found over the net is a code to copy ALL the RTB text.

Any ideas how to get just the text in the line that was clicked ?

Comment: I'm building the code with VS2008 C# so I need the answer with C# ...

Answer (score 2):

I made serious web digging and here is a working solution.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  TextPointer t = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetPosition(richTextBox1), true);

  string textAfterCursor  = t.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
  string textBeforeCursor = t.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward);

  string FullParagraphText = textBeforeCursor+textAfterCursor;
  MessageBox.Show(FullParagraphText);
}
```

(thanks to Justin-Josef with his post :
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/01/29/tapuz-net-getting-wpf-s-flowdocument-and-flowdoucmentreader-mouseover-text.aspx
)

Comment: This isn't correct as a line can be composed of multiple runs. In fact you can have a word made up of 2 runs.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is correct:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextPointer tp = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetPosition(richTextBox1), true);

    TextPointer line_start = tp.GetLineStartPosition(0);
    var nextStart = pos.GetLineStartPosition(1);
    TextPointer lineEnd = (nextStart != null ? nextStart : pos.DocumentEnd).GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);

    TextRange tr = new TextRange(line_start, lineEnd);
    string line = tr.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OOPS, I concated the strings in reverse order. 
Here is the revised code ... :)
Ohad.

```
   private void richTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextPointer t = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetPosition(richTextBox1), true);

        string textAfterCursor  = t.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        string textBeforeCursor = t.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward);

        string FullParagraphText = textBeforeCursor+textAfterCursor;
        MessageBox.Show(FullParagraphText);


    }
```